# Inheritance from Parent Controller breaks Parent Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, inheritance

Right now I have three controllers.  Random (the parent), Menu & Name (the children).

I have several methods in RandomController that work on the database, but I want Menu & Name to specify different databases.  However, if I remove the database context declaration from Random, it throws all sorts of errors.

As a side note, Random will never be accessed on its own, it only exists to provide code for Menu & Name

The entire controller isn't really necessary, but here are some of the methods I have to give an idea.  All of the db. statements break when I move the ComboContext declaration to the children.

```
public class RandomController : Controller
{

    publicCombosContext db = new CombosContext();
    //
    // GET: /Home/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var rows = db.Combos.OrderBy(a => a.Id).ToArray();
        int arrLength = rows.Length;
        Random ran = new Random();

        Combo newCombo = new Combo
        {
            MainPrefix = rows[ran.Next(0, arrLength)].MainPrefix,
            MainDescriptor = rows[ran.Next(0, arrLength)].MainDescriptor,
            MainDish = rows[ran.Next(0, arrLength)].MainDish,
            Connector = rows[ran.Next(0, arrLength)].Connector,
            SecondaryDescriptor = rows[ran.Next(0, arrLength)].SecondaryDescriptor,
            SecondaryDish = rows[ran.Next(0, arrLength)].SecondaryDish
        };

        return View(newCombo);
    }
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View(new Combo());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Combo model)
    {
        db.Combos.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Create");
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        Combo editMe = db.Combos.Find(id);
        return View(editMe);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Combo editMe)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(editMe).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            return View(editMe);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it is to add an abstract property to the parent controller where the type is an interface implemented by the contexts you need to use.

```
public RandomController : Controller
{
    ...
    protected abstract IContext Db { get; }
    ...
}

public MenuController : RandomController
{
    private SomeContext db = new SomeContext();

    ...

    protected override IContext Db { get { return db; } }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Leave the db context in the parent controller as a `protected` member, and then pass the appropriate context into the constructor of each child controller using DI.

```
public class RandomController : Controller   
{
    protected readonly CombosContext db;

    protected RandomController (CombosContext db)
    {
        this.db = db;
    }

    ...
}


public class MenuController : RandomController
{
    public MenuController (CombosContext db)
        : base (db)
    {
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use dependency injection, you can just initialise the context inside the child constructors.

Comment: Or as a constructor parameter or abstract property.

Comment: This works fine for the Menu controller using Combos Context (like the parent), but when I get to the Name controller and begin using the NamesContext in the constructor, I get:


Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'Controllers.RandomController.RandomController(Models.CombosContext)' has some invalid arguments


Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Models.NameContext' to 'Models.CombosContext'

Comment: You need to use an interface common to both contexts for the type of the member.